# Getting started with grails 3.3.9 and PostgreSQL 12.7: Error "org.postgresql.Driver"

Tags: database, postgresql, gradle, grails, yaml

i tried to connect a postgresdatabase in my grails 3.3.9 project;
My posgrest server is working, since I can connect and operate on the posgres database from Intelli J 2021 databse, but I can't connect to grails 3.3.9.
The password and user are correct but it always throws me this error:

```
Running application...
2021-07-05 19:06:25.298 ERROR --- [           main] org.postgresql.Driver                        : Connection error: 

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: El servidor requiere autenticación basada en  contraseña, pero no se ha provisto ninguna contraseña.
```

And this mi Application.yml

```
hibernate:
   cache:
    queries: false
    use_second_level_cache: false
    use_query_cache: false

dataSource:
  IkebanaUsuarios:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: "org.postgresql.Driver"
    username: "postgres"
    password: "postgres"


environments:
    development:
      dataSource:
          dbCreate: update
          url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/IkebanaERP
test:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/IkebanaERP
production:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/IkebanaERP
        properties:
            jmxEnabled: true
            initialSize: 5
            maxActive: 50
            minIdle: 5
            maxIdle: 25
            maxWait: 10000
            maxAge: 600000
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
            validationQuery: SELECT 1
            validationQueryTimeout: 3
            validationInterval: 15000
            testOnBorrow: true
            testWhileIdle: true
            testOnReturn: false
            jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
            defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

and my build.graddle is this

```
.......
compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
compile "org.grails.plugins:events"
compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.16.Final"
compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp"
console "org.grails:grails-console"
profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
runtime "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.1.2-b03"
runtime "com.h2database:h2"
runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.15.1"

runtime 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.6.17'
runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1208.jre1.8'
runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.1.jre7'

testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
}
```

Help pleases; thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are defining properties for your `IkebanaUsuarios` dataSource, but not for the default one used by Grails.

You may remove the `IkebanaUsuarios` block, leaving this:

```
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: "org.postgresql.Driver"
    username: "postgres"
    password: "postgres"
```

Or, if you needed that secondary datasource as well, you may define properties for both.  I'm guessing you did not need it, since you did not mention intentionally having two.

Comment: its work !!!!! I hasve the error too in  domain class Usuarios.groovy that have the sentence "static mapping = {datasource 'IkebanaUsuarios'}"   Thank you very much, my best regarst !!